# How to install NetSpeed from git source code

Tags: 17.10, github, git-buildpackage

How do you install NetSpeed from https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed?

I tried with

```
$ git-clone https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed.git
$ cd NetSpeed
```

So far fine, but then

```
$ ./configure --options 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

which didn't work.

The configure file doesn't exist,

```
$ ls -l 
total 120
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon  3051 mar 26 22:41 CHANGELOG
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon   978 mar 26 22:41 extension.js
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon 17893 mar 26 22:41 gpl-2.0.md
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon  2300 mar 26 22:41 layout_menu_item.js
drwxr-xr-x 10 pantheon pantheon  4096 mar 26 23:23 locale
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pantheon pantheon  1200 mar 26 22:41 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon   371 mar 26 22:41 metadata.json
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon 11336 mar 26 22:41 net_speed.js
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon  9248 mar 26 22:41 net_speed_status_icon.js
drwxr-xr-x  2 pantheon pantheon  4096 mar 26 22:41 po
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon  8832 mar 26 22:41 prefs.js
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon    40 mar 26 22:41 README
drwxr-xr-x  2 pantheon pantheon  4096 mar 26 22:48 schemas
-rw-r--r--  1 pantheon pantheon   224 mar 26 22:41 stylesheet.css
```

What am I doing wrong/ what should I try with?

Comment: I have barely ever used git before.

Comment: You have a Makefile. Which means the build command is `make`. Please do not always expect a build to start with ./configure ... There are ~10 other ways : cmake, qmake, 'python setup.py build', scons, './waf configure', jam, bjam, 'perl Makefile.PL', 'perl Build.PL', ant, mvn, etc.

Comment: Read 'README', of course!

Comment: @KnudLarsen, I actually tried wit that line of reasoning (more like guessing), but I never really understood what to do after that and was also uncertain about what to do after this. It only generated a 'locale' (I forgot to delete that file from the output of 'ls -l' up there) and a file called 'netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com.zip' (backup? idk). So thanks for the clarification - and yes, I should have added these thoughts to my orifginal post the first time - but what would the next step be after doing a 'make' and a 'sudo make install'?

Comment: @KnudLarsen, do you know where I can find the documentation? I tried to search for it, but didn't find it obvious where it was. I would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: NetSpeed → An extension for gnome 3 to show internet speed : JavaScript . ... Probably an applet ? ... No documentation.